# Spring Webflux: backpressure for non Java client

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

Is there any way to use backpressure for non Java subscriber(for example, some JS lib)?

For this Publisher

```
Flux.range(1, 100)
```

and this Subscriber:

```
public class SystemOutBackpressureSubscriber<T> extends BaseSubscriber<T> {

    private int delay;

    public SystemOutBackpressureSubscriber(int delay) {
        this.delay = delay;
    }

    public void hookOnSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
        request(1);
    }

    public void hookOnNext(T value) {
        System.out.println(value);
        if(delay != 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        request(1);
    }
}
```

if `delay == 0` all numbers printed at once, but if `delay != 0` there is pause before each number printed. Is there any way to do same but with JS? In all examples in internet which I looked at, JS client can only listen to event stream. If Rest controller returns producer like `Flux.range(1, 100)`, is it possible to vary frequency of events on client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as the HTTP protocol does not support application backpressure.
You'll probably be interested by [RSocket](http://rsocket.io/), which is an application protocol that supports backpressure at the protocol level, amongst many other features.